# How to compute $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p^{-n})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

We know it converges for any prime $p$. I just want to know how to compute its exact value:
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p^{-n})$$

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I doubt this has a closed form evaluation. Or, do you want to ask for computing approximations. In any case this is a particular value of the Euler function (or Q-Pochhammer symbol). 
It would also help in assesing whether this question is on-topic here, if you could give some context why and what exactly you want to know related to this. (Cf FAQ and How to ask). 

Comment: I just know it is 1/4 if p=2. But I don't know how to prove it. Now I want to generalize it. So comes this question.

Comment: I don't think that's right: when $p=2$ you get $0.288788\dots$.  Is there an error in how the question was phrased?

Comment: I'm away from my references, but I'm pretty sure it's not $1/4$ when $p=2$. It's related to the Dedekind eta-function. 

Comment: Numerical evaluation suggests that this product is 0.288788, not 0.25, at $p=2$. (I computed 20 terms and then 30 terms and got the same answer to 6 digits.) It shouldn't be hard to rigorously show that the product is more than 0.26.

Comment: The infinite terms are less then 1, so 0.25 is OK!

Comment: I came across this product some years ago, in its role as the asymptotic probability (as $n\to\infty$) that an $n\times n$ matrix over the $p$-element field is non-singular.  If I remember correctly, I had some reason then for believing that there isn't a simple expression (like $1/4$) for the product when $p=2$, but I don't now remember what the reason was or how convincing it was.  I do remember using an Excel spreadsheet to compute the partial product out to at least 20 terms, but I think my reason was not just "by inspection of the spreadsheet".

Comment: This product also shows up in the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics for the distribution of p-Sylow subgroups of class groups of imaginary quadratic fields. This is expected to be related to Andreas Blass's comment about the probability that an n by n matrix over F_p is nonsingular, thanks to a paper of Friedman and Washington.

Comment: I think I waited long enough for some clarification. Vote to close as not a real question, in particular since, as meanwhile is amply documented, it seems based on a false premise. 

Comment: Well, I learned that this number, which I call "the Cohen-Lenstra constant," is also called the q-Pochhammer symbol!  Is it actually known to be irrational?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a recent question?  I don't find it now, though.  Anyway, as Gerry says, see "Dedekind eta function" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram MathWorld gives the expression of this product in terms of the q-Pochhammer symbol and the Jacobi theta function. See formulas (46) and (47) in

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html

Comment: Well, it is a q-Pochhammer symbol essentially by definition (as I commented).

Comment: Yes, it is. But its exact value is still very difficult.

Comment: Determining its exact value is unlikely to be a well-posed question.

Answer (score 24):

Let's fix the issue of giving bounds on the infinite product. The [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) gives, after grouping pairs of consecutive terms with the same sign, an [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) with terms that are decreasing in modulus. So for instance for $c:=\prod _ {n\ge1} (1-2^{-n})$ one has

$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{128} -\frac{1}{4096}-\frac{1}{ 32768 } <   c  <  1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{32}+\frac{1}{128}$$ that is  $ 0.288787842 < c <  0.2890625, $ in any case larger than $1/4$.

Comment: +1 for including this information and thus avoiding the possiblilty of any confusion on this matter. 

Comment: You can find it in GTM 245, P209 , ex 1.

Comment: Now even in the notes of my calculus course, why. ;-)

Comment: Note that this problem has nothing to do with primes. The product converges if $|p|>1$. 

Answer (score 2):

The [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) is
$$
\eta = q^{1/24}\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-q^k) = 
e^{\pi i \tau/12}\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-e^{2\pi i k \tau})
$$
which converges for complex $q$ with $|q| < 1$.  It is often written in terms of a complex argument $\tau$ with $\text{Im}\;\tau > 0$, where $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$.
The factor $q^{1/24}$ in front gives this desirable number-theoretic properties, but clearly it can be evaluated with that factor if and only if it can be evaluated without.

Some exact values are known for the eta function (see the Wikipedia page).  But not $q=1/p$, $p$ prime.