# Lower bound for Euler's function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, limits-and-convergence, lower-bounds, products

[Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) is defined, for $|x|\le 1$, as follows:
$$\phi(x)=\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-x^i)$$

Upper bounds for $\phi$ can be simply derived from ending the product early, e.g.
$$\phi(x)<\prod_{i=1}^2(1-x^i)=1-x-x^2+x^3$$

> **What lower bounds are known for $\phi(x)$**?

---

I'm especially interested in bounds which can be computed efficiently as this is needed for a computer application.

Comment: `mpmath` can compute it exactly, does this help?

Comment: @joro - Seems good, if it's fast enough. Thanks !

Comment: It is very efficient with 100 decimal digits of precision. Answered with details.

Comment: Also, mpmath is open source, written in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mpmath](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/functions/qfunctions.html) can compute it very efficiently.

The function is called `mpmath.qp`. Here is a sage session for $\phi(e^{-\pi})$
with precision 100 decimal digits which takes about 360 microseconds on and old machine:

```
sage: time mpmath.qp(mpmath.exp(-mpmath.pi))
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 361 µs
0.9549187899876741037512339781102910776327153738078052831487991916760940356867145395349815186744610988
```

This agrees with wikipedia's closed form for 
$$\phi(e^{-\pi})=\frac{e^{\pi/24}\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2^{7/8}\pi^{3/4}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You get concrete bounds from above or from below just stopping the well-known expansion after two positive terms, resp. two consecutive negative terms; see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104685/how-to-compute-prod-n-1-infty-1-p-n/104715#104715).